# Slice a string by regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So I want to split a string by space unless that part of the string is in exclamation marks.

Sample:

```
ABC DEF !GHI JKL MNO! PQR
```

Would become:

```
["ABC", "DEF", "GHI JKL MNO", "PQR"]
```

Currently, this is my regex (I checked it with regex101.com and it worked)

```
[^\s]*![^!]*![^\s]*|[^\s!!]+
```

And my code to split it is

```
sample = "ABC DEF !GHI JKL MNO! PQR"
print(sample.split(r"[^\s]*![^!]*![^\s]*|[^\s!!]+").strip("!"))
```

Comment: why escape the exclamation mark?

Comment: Didn't know you didn't have to escape it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match the expected substrings using

```
res = re.findall(r'![^!]*!|\S+', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBQjTK/1).

**Details**

- `![^!]*!` - matches a `!`, then any 0+ chars other than `!` and again a `!`
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/eqOOxB):

```
import re
rx = r"![^!]*!|\S+"
s = "ABC DEF !GHI JKL MNO! PQR"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['ABC', 'DEF', '!GHI JKL MNO!', 'PQR']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
def splitIt(sample):
    exclamation = False
    result = []
    for i in sample:
        if i == " ":
            if exclamation == False:
                result.append("")
            else:
                pass
        elif i == "!":
            if not exclamation:
                exclamation = True
            else:
                exclamation = False
        else:
            result[-1] += i
    return result
```